# Repeatedly Render Dust.js Template with New Data

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api, dust.js, client-side-templating

What would be the best way to go about repeatedly rendering a dust template while having it advance in the data file its referencing rather than just repeat from the start each time. For example:

Say I have a list of 100+ people stored as JSON in a variable called **data**:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Jerry",
            "age": "17"
        },
        {
            "name": "Darcy",
            "age": "19"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jacob",
            "age": "25"
        },
        ... and so on for 100 or so people
    ]
}
```

And I have this **template.tl** file that exports a row of three names/ages:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>{name} - {age}</div>
    <div>{name} - {age}</div>
    <div>{name} - {age}</div>
</div>
```

Which I precompile into **template.js**:

```
(function(){dust.register("template.tl",body_0);function body_0(chk,ctx){return chk.write("<div class=\"row\"><div>").reference(ctx.get(["name"], false),ctx,"h").write(" - ").reference(ctx.get(["age"], false),ctx,"h").write("</div><div>").reference(ctx.get(["name"], false),ctx,"h").write(" - ").reference(ctx.get(["age"], false),ctx,"h").write("</div><div>").reference(ctx.get(["name"], false),ctx,"h").write(" - ").reference(ctx.get(["age"], false),ctx,"h").write("</div></div>");}return body_0;})();
```

Then I have an **index.html** file that looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="people"></div>

        <button id="load-more" type="button">Load More</button>
    </body>

    <script src="js/dust-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/template.js"></script>
</html>
```

What would be the best way to have it so each time the button is clicked, a row of three people would be appended inside the `<div id="people"></div>`, and each subsequent click would load the next three / test for the end of the data array (can assume the number of people is always a multiple of three for my needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change *template.tl* to:

```
<div class="row">
    {#.}
        <div>{.name} - {.age}</div>
    {/.}
</div>
```

There are 2 benefits to changing the template:

- You can pass in any number of `people` objects, not just 3.
- If you only have 2 elements left in the array, it will still render correctly.

---

### JavaScript to perform the rendering:

```
$('#load-more').on('click', function(){
    var next3 = data.people.splice(0, 3);

    if(next3.length == 0){
        return; // Array is empty
    }

    dust.render('template.tl', next3, function(err, str){
        if(str){
            $('#people').append(str);
        }
    });
});
```

The most important part is `data.people.splice(0, 3)`, this removes 3 elements from the array and returns them - See [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

The rest of the code is just JQuery to add an event listener and insert the rendered template.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2QDJ/)